# How to output geojson from a collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, geojson, rgeo

I want to output a geojson file from my rails app using rgeo-geojson. I have a table of points each with lat and long.

I have my controller set up in the standard way

`respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.csv { send_data @nodes_for_map.to_csv }
      format.json {  send_data  @nodes_for_map.as_geo_json  }
    end`

How do create the geojson from the collection?

rgeo-geojson FeatureCollection

Answer (score 1):

This will respond with a JSON body:

```
format.json { render json: RGeo::GeoJSON.encode(@nodes_for_map).to_json }
```

This will respond with a JSON file:

```
format.json do 
  send_data RGeo::GeoJSON.encode(@nodes_for_map).to_json,
    filename: "whatever.json",
    type: "text/plain"
end
```

Comment: thanks for this.  doing it that way, How do i make sure my @nodes_for_map has the correct fields (lat, long etc) and set the properties (marker color for eg) ?